# Converting C# component to .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, tabcontrol

I am trying to use the component below in my vb.net program

[Custom Tab Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12185/A-NET-Flat-TabControl-CustomDraw)

What I'm having troubles with is errors saying `SuspendLayout` is not a member of `FlatTabControl.FlatTabControl`, and even with `Controls` not being a member of `FlatTabControl`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Below is the C# code which I converted to VB.Net code, still can't get it working.

Cheers.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace TabControlTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    private FlatTabControl.FlatTabControl tabControl1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imageList1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage4;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.tabControl1 = new FlatTabControl.FlatTabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.tabPage3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.tabPage4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.imageList1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage4);
        this.tabControl1.ImageList = this.imageList1;
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 16);
        this.tabControl1.myBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 240);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.tabPage1.ImageIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 25);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 211);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
        // 
        // tabPage2
        // 
        this.tabPage2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
        this.tabPage2.ImageIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 25);
        this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
        this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 71);
        this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage2.Text = "tabPage2";
        // 
        // tabPage3
        // 
        this.tabPage3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
        this.tabPage3.ImageIndex = 2;
        this.tabPage3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 25);
        this.tabPage3.Name = "tabPage3";
        this.tabPage3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 71);
        this.tabPage3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tabPage3.Text = "tabPage3";
        // 
        // tabPage4
        // 
        this.tabPage4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
        this.tabPage4.ImageIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 25);
        this.tabPage4.Name = "tabPage4";
        this.tabPage4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 71);
        this.tabPage4.TabIndex = 3;
        this.tabPage4.Text = "tabPage4";
        // 
        // imageList1
        // 
        this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
        this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
        this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(1, "");
        this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(2, "");
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(352, 160);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Add";
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(352, 208);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button3.Text = "Remove";
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(448, 269);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "FlatTabControl test";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private static int nt = 0;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tabPage = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage("newTab");

        switch (nt)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                tabPage.ImageIndex = 0;
                nt = 1;
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            {
                tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                tabPage.ImageIndex = 1;
                nt = 2;
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
                tabPage.ImageIndex = 2;
                nt = 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be .Net C#... Perhaps you mean converting C# to VB.Net? And please include your vb code as well if so.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new c#-project and place this control inside there. Then in your VB-Solution you should be able to reference the ControlDll and use the control

Comment: Where did you get FlatTabControl from? It's a third party control so perhaps you just forgot to add a reference to the assembly/dll that contains the code for that control?

Comment: @BrutalDev It's on codeproject, there is a link... And yeah, just reference it...

Comment: *Converting C# to .NET* .... hmmm.... C# ***IS*** a .NET language, there's **absolutely NO NEED** to convert anything ....

Comment: @marc_s I already said that... Kind of :P. And you can use c# for things other than .net...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Added the actual test project I made that I am referring to below: http://www.brutaldev.com/file.axd?file=FlatTabExample-18627930.zip

Firstly, you need to download the FlatTabControl.dll file from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/FlatTabControl/FlatTabControl_demo.zip

Create a new Windows Forms VB.NET project in Visual Studio, add a reference to FlatTabControl.dll (right click -> Add Reference). You can also drag and drop the assembly onto the toolbox so that you can easily add it to your form, this will also create a reference as soon as you drop it on your form.

I converted your C# code to VB.NET and it should look like something like this.

**Form1.Designer.vb** - You should leave this to be generated by Visual Studio but for completeness I'm including it here.

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.tabControl1 = New FlatTabControl.FlatTabControl()
    Me.TabPage1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
    Me.TabPage2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.tabControl1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'tabControl1
    '
    Me.tabControl1.Controls.Add(Me.TabPage1)
    Me.tabControl1.Controls.Add(Me.TabPage2)
    Me.tabControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
    Me.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1"
    Me.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Me.tabControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(265, 202)
    Me.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'TabPage1
    '
    Me.TabPage1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 25)
    Me.TabPage1.Name = "TabPage1"
    Me.TabPage1.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Me.TabPage1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(257, 173)
    Me.TabPage1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.TabPage1.Text = "TabPage1"
    Me.TabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TabPage2
    '
    Me.TabPage2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 25)
    Me.TabPage2.Name = "TabPage2"
    Me.TabPage2.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Me.TabPage2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(192, 71)
    Me.TabPage2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.TabPage2.Text = "TabPage2"
    Me.TabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 222)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button2
    '
    Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(99, 222)
    Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
    Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.Button2.TabIndex = 2
    Me.Button2.Text = "Button2"
    Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(290, 268)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.tabControl1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

  End Sub
  Friend WithEvents tabControl1 As FlatTabControl.FlatTabControl
  Friend WithEvents TabPage1 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
  Friend WithEvents TabPage2 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
  Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button

End Class
```

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Shared nt As Integer = 0

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tabPage As TabPage = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage("newTab")

    Select Case nt
      Case 0
        If True Then
          tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightCoral
          tabPage.ImageIndex = 0
          nt = 1
        End If
        Exit Select

      Case 1
        If True Then
          tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
          tabPage.ImageIndex = 1
          nt = 2
        End If
        Exit Select

      Case 2
        If True Then
          tabPage.BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen
          tabPage.ImageIndex = 2
          nt = 0
        End If
        Exit Select
    End Select

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
  End Sub
End Class
```